# Access Parent component properties in Child component's html file

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-components

I want to access the variable/property declared in Parent component into Child's view. Is it possible?

```
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
  public example: string;
  constructor(){
    this.example = 'display this';
}}

@Component({templateUrl: './child.component.html',})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent implements OnInit{...}
```

**child.component.html**

< div>{{ example }}< /div>

Comment: Are you extending the parents just to have `example`in the child? If yes, you can use `@Input` instead and solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Input to pass data from parent to child to access parent component properties into child component